# C++ calling one function repeatedly system hang

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I am getting very serious issue with one function in C++. This is my function

```
double** Fun1(unsigned l,unsigned n, vector<int>& list,
                    vector<string>& DataArray)
{
  double** array2D = 0;
  array2D = new double*[l];     
  string alphabet="ACGT";   
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
  {
        array2D[i] = new double [4];
        vector<double> count(4, 0.0);
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
            {
                if (toupper(DataArray[list[j]][i])==alphabet[k])
                   count[k]=count[k]+1;
            }

        }

    for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
        array2D[i][k]=count[k];  

       count.clear();
  }

  return array2D;
}
```

The value of l is around 100 and n=1, DataArray size is (50000 x l) and list will contain any one number between 0-49999. 
Now i am calling this function from my main program many number of times (may be like more than 50 Million times). Upto certain number of times it going very smooth but after 2/3 minute around that my system hangs. I am unable to find what is problem with this code. I guess memory is getting short but don't know why?

Comment: Lots of `new`s, where are the `delete`s?

Comment: Because you don't use `delete[]`.

Comment: Memory leaks ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak ) lead to thrashing ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science) _

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the corresponding `delete[]` from your code.

Note the `[]` which means you are deleting an array. If you forget to add these you will be venturing into undefined territory (3.7.4.2 in [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)).

You may wish to try using `std::array` to mitigate having to `new` and `delete[]` so much. Also if this is called as much as you say and the loop is this small I would be concerned about the coherency of the data.

Comment: *If you forget to add these you will only delete the first element.* actually, it's plain undefined behavior. I've seen VC++ work fine (the two operators, at least in older versions, were forwarded to the same code) and g++ crash on `new[]`/`delete[]` mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

> Upto certain number of times it going very smooth but after 2/3 minute
>   around that my system hangs

its not hang. If you are working on `linux` or `unix` machine check `top (system performance)`. virtual memory of your system got full. Do `delete` or `delete[]` appropriately for every `new`